# mySQL - inner join three tables

Tags: mysql

The final question on my database. I have triad several approaches to get the receipt for the customer for the transaction in my DB.

```
customer_tbl - customer_ID PK
transaction_tbl - customer_ID FK
Payment_tbl - customer_id FK
```

I wonder if you could please help and based on that I will add game title, rental date, return date and total payment?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Add more information- tables, the query, etc

Comment: customer_tbl (customer_id, first_name, second_name), transaction_tbl (transaction_id, rental_date, return_date, game_id FK, payment_id FK, customer_id FK), payment_tbl (payment_id, paid). Won't copy my JOIN functions as neither of them worked. I am ok to link to tables but struggle with three. As you can see the transaction_tbl is the main one which links customer to game to payment. Any help is much appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves my transaction report. I

```
SELECT t.* , g.game_name , p.* 
FROM transaction_tbl t 
INNER JOIN game_tbl g ON g.game_id = t.game_id 
INNER JOIN payment_tbl p ON p.payment_id = t.payment_id 
WHERE t.customer_id = 1;
```

It works for any given customer (in this case '1') and it selects FKs from transaction_tbl and dates. From customer_tbl you have only customer _id (similar to shops where you get only your loyalty card number) and payment details from payment_tbl. Learned a lot and thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The JOIN should take the form of:

```
SELECT ... FROM customer_tbl c 
JOIN transaction_tbl t on c.customer_id = t.customer_id
JOIN Payment_tbl p ON t.payment_id = p.payment_id;
```

If you want more details, you'll have to provide more information from your side.

Comment: nearly there - above shows all transactions for all customers and I need per one customer. I have WHERE = customer_id = '1' but with no luck. I have this select: SELECT * FROM customer_tbl
JOIN transaction_tbl on customer_tbl.customer_id = transaction_tbl.customer_id 
JOIN Payment_tbl ON transaction_tbl.payment_id = payment_tbl.payment_id ; it gives as I said before all records for all customers.

Comment: I'd try one of the following.

1. On the first JOIN, set the condition as "ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id and c.customer_id = 'value' 

2. Add WHERE customer_id = 'value' at the end of the query.

You said you tried 2 with no luck. What results did you get?

Comment: it worked for the customer: SELECT * FROM customer_tbl c 
JOIN transaction_tbl t on c.customer_id = t.customer_id and c.customer_id = '1'
JOIN Payment_tbl p ON t.payment_id = p.payment_id; now I am trying to use transaction_tbl to link the customer, game and the payment. The code I have come up is select * from transaction_tbl t
JOIN customer_tbl c ON t.customer_id = c.customer_id and t.customer_id = '1'
JOIN payment tbl p ON t.payment_id = p.payment_id; but is is not working?

Comment: In the code you have pasted, there is a missing "_" in payment_tbl. Is this just a paste error?

What do you mean by it's not working?. What results or error do you get?

Comment: modified and worked. select * from transaction_tbl t JOIN customer_tbl c ON t.customer_id = c.customer_id and t.customer_id = '1' JOIN payment_tbl p ON t.payment_id = p.payment_id; it gives me all data but no game name? it gives for example all fileds from customer_tbl and wonder if we can have just customer_id?

Comment: To get the game name, you will need an additional JOIN, with the table containing those names, probably on game_id.

To get only some of the fiedls, instead of `select *`, use `select customer_tbl.customer_id`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
SELECT t.* , p.* FROM transaction_tbl t INNER JOIN payment_tbl p 
ON p.payment_id = t.payment_id WHERE t.customer_id = 1;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.